# How to change the files administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, administrator

Recently, I've reinstalled Windows 10 and logged into my account made from previous windows and tried to put something on C partition but requested administrator.

As far as I knew, I was thinking there was just 1 account, but there was 1 more, an Administrator.

I've read about it and that is a built-in administrator that windows 10 makes bla bla.

I managed to get rid of this account and now it's just mine.

Again, I tried to put something on C but again it requested an administrator. I do not know what to do, searched the internet but in vain.

Strange is that the Security tab from C partition points to another name of administrator.

This is my account:

> [image]

This is what I see on Security tab:

[image]

Comment: Which folder makes a difference. Root of C?

Comment: The Security tab shows a **Group** called Adminstrators. Gropus may contain multiple users.

Comment: @Anonymous The clue that this was a group and not a single user was that there is an "s" on the end of the word "Administrators." The same goes for the "Users" group.